# AWS Cloudsearch doc upload url

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudsearch

Is there anyway to use AWS Gateway API as a proxy for Cloudsearch with uploading documents? We have our project setup with our authorization through the API and do not want to reconfigure our security for this?

Comment: Have you investigated creating [an AWS Service Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-aws-proxy.html) that calls the [Document Service API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/document-service-api.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use API Gateway with the AWS Service Proxy integration to upload documents to your CloudSearch documents API. I've set this up before and gotten it to work.  If you've made your document service API private, such that it requires sigV4 to access, then your CloudSearch domain and your API Gateway must be owned by the same account.